# Readline 'close' event firing after reading the first row of a txt file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am coding a server using Node.js, I need to read lines from a txt file using the readline module. The problem I have is that the 'close' event fires after reading the first row of the file, where am I wrong?

```
    rl.on('line', function (line) {
        var longest=true;

        nLines++;
        var words=line.split(" ");
        nWords += words.length;
        wordsPerLine[nLines] = words.length;
        for(len in wordsPerLine) if(len > words.length) longest=false;
        if(longest) longestLine=nLines;
        console.log("Line: ",nLines," - ",words.length," words, "," is the longest: ",longest);
        rl.close();
    }).on('close',function (line) {
        console.log("Counted: "+nWords+" words, longest line is number "+longestLine);
        res.write(getResponse(file, nLines,nWords, wordsPerLine,longestLine)); 
        res.end();
    });
```

Comment: Why would you use readline? The latest release was 7 years ago and you could just use native with a sane version of Node

Comment: You are calling `rl.close();` yourself, so of course it closes? I am so confused with this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the rl.close inside the event handler. It will never finish the process of your file. Your readline will call closed event after the end of the lines.
Follow this example:

```
(() => {
    var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.txt')
    });

    rl.on('line', function (line) {
      console.log(line)
    });

    rl.on('close', function (line) {
       console.log("close")
    });
})()
```

Read more in the [node.js official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line).

Follow these another options to do the same thing that you're trying to do: https://geshan.com.np/blog/2021/10/nodejs-read-file-line-by-line/

Comment: Thank you, but now I have another problem, the readline interface is closed immediately after the opening, before reading anything :(

Comment: @Alberto I updated my answer and fixed my mistake, try again please

Comment: Now it works, that you :)